# HTML5 Canvas page hangs in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, internet-explorer-9, html5-canvas

[TimingCharts.com](http://timingcharts.com/) loads in FireFox, Chrome, Safari and Android devices but hangs in IE9.  If I hit F12 and click on just about anything within the developer settings, such as debug, Browser mode, Images etc., the page will then load.  As long as I leave the browser open the page continues to work fine.  If I close the browser and come back in though, I have to go through the f12 process again.

Several users have confirmed they have the same problem.  Can someone tell me what I need to do to make this page load correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Hah I know why. I sent a bug report to Microsoft for this in the IE9 beta! They never replied :-(

You have a `console.log` on your page and that fouls up IE9 unless developer tools are open. This is a really stupid bug, because as soon as you go to investigate with developer tools, the bug disappears!

You can make it always work by wrapping your statement like this:

```
if (window.console !== undefined && window.console.log !== undefined) {
  console.log('some console output');
}
```

That should let IE9 work again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the direction Simon!  After working with your example for a while I settled on...

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}};
    </script>
</head>
```

This seems to have fixed the problem.  I really appreciate your help.